# Use Auth0's hook to get token and set header in Apollo client

Tags: next.js, apollo-client, auth0

Hello I'm trying to get auth0 token and set it in the request with next.js, however I haven't been able to set it.

I think the cause is that the function "authLink" in apollo-client.tsx is not called.

I would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

## apollo-client.tsx

```
import { createHttpLink,ApolloClient, InMemoryCache} from "@apollo/client";
import { setContext } from "@apollo/link-context";
import { Auth0ContextInterface } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

function createClient(
  getAccessTokenSilently: Auth0ContextInterface["getAccessTokenSilently"],
){
  const endpointUri ="http://localhost:8080/v1/graphql"
  console.log("hoge")
  const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
    const accessToken = await getAccessTokenSilently();
    console.log(accessToken)
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      },
    };
  });

  const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: endpointUri,
  });
  return new ApolloClient({
    link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });
}

export {createClient};
```

## _app.tsx

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import Head from 'next/head'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client'
import { createClient } from './api/apollo-client'
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'
import { CacheProvider, EmotionCache } from '@emotion/react';
import theme from '../src/theme'
import createEmotionCache from '../src/createEmotionCache'
import { Auth0Provider,useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react'
import { FC,ReactNode } from 'react'


const clientSideEmotionCache = createEmotionCache();
interface MyAppProps extends AppProps {
  emotionCache?: EmotionCache;
}
const AuthApolloProvider: FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
  const client = createClient(getAccessTokenSilently);
  return <ApolloProvider client={client}>{children}</ApolloProvider>;
};

function MyApp({ Component, emotionCache = clientSideEmotionCache, pageProps }: MyAppProps) {
  return (
    <Auth0Provider
    domain={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH0_DOMAIN||""}
    clientId={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID||""}
    redirectUri={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL}/`}
    audience={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH0_AUDIENCE||""}
        >
       <CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
       <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
      </Head>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <AuthApolloProvider>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </AuthApolloProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
    </Auth0Provider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

I wanted to call the function authLink to get toke and set it in the request header but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is that your code is not waiting for the function getAccessTokenSilently to return token as parent function's callback is async but you are not awaiting for it.

Try below:

***apollo-client.tsx***

```
import { createHttpLink,ApolloClient, InMemoryCache} from "@apollo/client";
import { setContext } from "@apollo/link-context";
import { Auth0ContextInterface } from "@auth0/auth0-react";


// Made it async
async function createClient(
  getAccessTokenSilently: Auth0ContextInterface["getAccessTokenSilently"],
){
  const endpointUri ="http://localhost:8080/v1/graphql"
  console.log("hoge");

  // Moved it out of set context
  const accessToken = await getAccessTokenSilently();

  // removed async from setContext as its no more needed
  const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    console.log(accessToken)
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      },
    };
  });

  const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: endpointUri,
  });
  return new ApolloClient({
    link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });
}

export {createClient};
```

***_app.tsx***

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import Head from 'next/head'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client'
import { createClient } from './api/apollo-client'
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'
import { CacheProvider, EmotionCache } from '@emotion/react';
import theme from '../src/theme'
import createEmotionCache from '../src/createEmotionCache'
import { Auth0Provider,useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react'
import { FC,ReactNode } from 'react'


const clientSideEmotionCache = createEmotionCache();
interface MyAppProps extends AppProps {
  emotionCache?: EmotionCache;
}
const AuthApolloProvider: FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();

  // You cannot directly await in JSX function so use useState and useEffect

  // useState to store client
  const [client, setClient] = React.useState();

  // UseEffect to load client
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    // useEffect will not allow await, so create a function and use it to await 
    const generateClient = async () => {
      const generatedClient = await createClient(getAccessTokenSilently);
      setClient(generatedClient);
    }
    generateClient();
  },[])
  
  return <ApolloProvider client={client}>{children}</ApolloProvider>;
};

function MyApp({ Component, emotionCache = clientSideEmotionCache, pageProps }: MyAppProps) {
  return (
    <Auth0Provider
    domain={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH0_DOMAIN||""}
    clientId={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID||""}
    redirectUri={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL}/`}
    audience={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH0_AUDIENCE||""}
        >
       <CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
       <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
      </Head>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <AuthApolloProvider>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </AuthApolloProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
    </Auth0Provider>
  )
}

export default MyApp;
```